# Setting up Graphics in Visual Studio C++ 2013

Tags: c++, graphics, visual-studio-2013

I've decided to move my game from Java to C++ (haven't used C++ before)

How do I set up the graphics for C++ (the public void paint(Graphics g) equivalent)?

I've tried following two tutorials:
http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/msvsnet2010e/index.php
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/376205-defeating-sdl-linker-errors-in-visual-studio-net/

The first one gave me build errors related to the linker not being able to find the SDL.h header.  The second one built correctly, but I wasn't sure where and how to put my graphics.  Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use some kind of API, such as OpenGL or DirectX.  C++ has no built in graphics functions at all.

[RasterTek DirectX11 Tutorial](http://www.rastertek.com/tutdx11.html)

I've used this tutorial for DirectX 11 very successfully and it lays the groundwork for a solid architecture.  It's explained very clearly and decently in depth if you follow through with it all.

I don't use OpenGL often so I can't recommend any good tutorials off the top of my head.

Comment: Is it compatible with 2013?

Comment: I believe he uses VS2010 in his examples but I've a renderer that I based on this and I did it in VS2012.  It should be fine, maybe with a couple quirks you may have to work around.

Comment: Also, I know for a fact if you're on Windows 8 and want to use his exact code to copy and past to try and learn, you'll have to do a bit of work.  The Windows 8 SDK changes many function calls.

Comment: Curse you Windows 8...
But thanks for the help.  Much appreciated

Comment: Don't give up on it, it's really not that hard of a change.  I modified my project to use the legacy SDK in about an hour or two, max.  Especially if you do it from the start.

Comment: Hmm.. it says DirectX SDK's are included automatically in the Windows 8 SDK now.  So does that mean I can basically skip Tutorial 1?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45304/discussion-between-nathan-chan-and-cspshala)

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in GUI or 3D/2D library within the standart library. C++'s standart library actually just contains the most important things (e.g strings, collections...) and is not nearly that big and comprehensive than the Java standart lib.

There are however multiple 3rd party libraries. You have to understand though, that these are actually just abstractions of the libraries provided by the OS.

**GUI**

- Qt
- WxWidgets

**3D**

- DirectX
- OpenGL